# Python Imports with packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a my projects set up like so(the name package is used isn't the name of the directory only for this example it has been used):

```
.
├── Installer\ Script.iss
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── TODO.md
├── docs
├── requirements.txt
├── resources
│   ├── logo.hqx
│   ├── logo.icns
│   ├── logo.ico
│   └── qt.conf
├── setup.py
└── project
    ├── Main.py
    ├── Controller.py
    ├── Updator.py
    ├── Updator.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── tests
    │   ├── TestController.py
    │   ├── TestUpdator.py
    │   ├── TestUpdator.pyc
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── ui.py
```

In my `Main.py` how should I import `ui.py`? Currently my code for importing looks like:

```
import project.ui as ui
```

Is this correct? As when I freeze the project with py2app it doesn't like my imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the the package that you want to import in the same directory, you just write "import ui" in your main.py can work as you want it to.If you want to import ui in you setup.py（just for example), you can do it what you ask above.
Hope this can help you .